# How do you configure dependent packages in a monorepo for publishing?

Tags: javascript, npm, package.json, monorepo, bun

I have a monorepo (using Bun.js workspaces) that has two packages, one dependent on the other. In addition, both these packages will be published for others to use on NPM.

The problem is that when the packages are published, one won't work because although it is dependent on the other, it's `package.json` lists it as a workspace dependency and not a registry one, meaning others can't use it.

What's the best way to handle this situation? Should I have an automated script that replaces `workspace:*` in `package.json` with a version number on publish, or is there some way I can have it automatically defer to the registry when it's not available as a workspace package?

Here's a look at the `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "@stylecss/cli",
  "description": "This package provides a CLI for Style, a simple & practical CSS preprocessor.",
  "author": {
    "name": "Aarvin R."
  },
  "homepage": "https://stylecss.js.org/",
  "module": "src/cli.ts",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "@stylecss/compiler": "workspace:*" // <<<<< Dependency that doesn't work when installing this package
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bun": "latest"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/aarvinr/style.git",
    "directory": "packages/cli"
  },
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

Comment: see [pnpm publish](https://pnpm.io/cli/publish) and [changesets](https://github.com/changesets/changesets) for examples

Comment: So are you suggesting I have a script that changes the package.json on prePublish?

Comment: I think you should also consider if a monorepo is appropiate for your requirements in this instance. npm packages are typically stored in their own dedicated repository